# Summarize to quantiles in using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose one is manipulating a dataframe in `dplyr`, and one would like to summarize one's data into a table with a column for each decile. Setting aside the question of *why* one would do this, there remains the question of *how.*

It has been [noted before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500407/dplyr-summarise-when-function-return-is-vector-valued) that `summarize` does not like vector-valued functions. As mentioned in that post, the most literal-minded way of doing it is simply to create an explicit column for each decile:

```
df <- data.frame(value=rnorm(1000)) %>%
    summarize(`0.1` = quantile(value, 0.1),
              `0.2` = quantile(value, 0.2), 
              `0.3` = quantile(value, 0.3),
              ...)
```

This, obviously, is vile. Yet it is not immediately obvious to me how to use `ddply` nor `do`, as mentioned in the linked question, to accomplish this goal. And it just feels like there ought to be a "tidy" way to do this, along the lines of:

```
df <- data.frame(value=rnorm(1000)) %>%
    summarize(quantiles = quantile(value, seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.1))) %>%
    expand_vector_to_columns()
```

Is there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373568/dplyr-to-iterate-over-all-columns-for-quantile

Comment: Bingo--trick is to `summarize` to a `list(quantile(...))`, with a second summary variable for labels. Then unnest. You get two columns, one with the value and one with a label, and that works even if the data is grouped and there are other columns to preserve.

Answer (score 1):

This might do it:

```
df <- data.frame(value=rnorm(1000))  %>%
unlist  %>% 
quantile(seq(.1, .9, .1)) %>% 
matrix(., 1,9, dimnames=list(NULL, names(.)))  %>%
as.data.frame(., col.names=colnames(.))
#df
#     10%     20%     30%     40%    50%    60%    70%    80%   90%
#1 -1.275 -0.8528 -0.5258 -0.2353 0.0303 0.3051 0.5732 0.8918 1.278
```